# cassandra not running in ubuntu

Tags: database, linux, ubuntu, cassandra

I'm used this command to Run Cassandra server in Ubuntu

```
sudo /etc/init.d/cassandra start
```

but terminal show this error how can solve it.

```
xss =  -ea -javaagent:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar    -XX:+UseThreadPriorities     -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms1006M -Xmx1006M -Xmn200M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss256k
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an error... this is a "launching message" of cassandra, reporting on JVM configuration parameters your have for cassandra.

To make sure that you have cassandra running (on background) run:

> ps -aux | grep cassandra

you should get a positive result (unless there is another error, in that case please update your question with more log info about the error).

HTH.